# Cumulative distribution function and convolution. 

Tags: probability-distributions

Hello,
Given a probability distribution of a discrete variable p1(x) and a probability distribution of a discrete variable p2(y) defined by 
p2(y) = Sum_{x,x'} p1(x) p1(x') * KroneckerDelta((x+x')/2 = y).    (1) 
Let F1(x) be the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of p1(x): F1(x) == Sum_{x'<=x} p1(x') and let F2(x) be the CDF p2(x).

Is there a way of expressing F2(x) ONLY in terms of F1(x)?
If there is none, is there any known (tight) upper and lower bound for F2(x) that is a function ONLY of F1(x)?

Thank you!
Best
Michele

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$, $Y$ be independent random variables and let $F_X$ and $F_Y$ denote their cumulative  distribution functions. Let and $Z=X+Y$, then $F_Z$ can be expressed in terms of $F_X$ and $F_Y$:
$$F_Z(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(t)F_Y(x-t)~dt.$$
Using the convolution '$*$', this can be written as $F_Z=(F_X*F_Y)'$.

With this we can express the $F_2$ in your problem in terms of $F_1$:
$$F_2(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_1(t)F_1(2x-t)~dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be your given discrete variable, with distribution $p1$, and $Y$ the second one
with distribution $p2$. Your definition of $Y$ means that $2Y$ is the sum of two independent
variables distributed like $X$. Thus the distribution of $2Y$ is the convolution
of the distribution of $X$ with itself.

That is:
$$G(y)=\int F(2y-x)dF(x)=\sum F(2y-x_j)\lambda_j,$$
where $F,G$ are the cumulative distributions of $X$, $Y$, $x_j$ are the values of $X$
and $\lambda_j=p1(x_j)$.

Comment: Dear Alexander, 
Thanks! But this doesn't answer my question...

Best
Michele

Comment: Why? Did not I tell you how to express the distribution of Y in terms
of the distribution of X?

Comment: Well the point is that in my question I specified that I need F2(y) as a function ONLY of F1(y). So maybe I was not clear enough but what I meant is that I want F2 as a function only of F1 and not of its finite differences (derivatives in the continuous case). The expression that you gave involves p1, which is the 'derivative' of F1. 